# how to get grand total from php using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Now its 3rd day i am trying to figure out how to get grand total updated when qty changes . i have made it for price and totals this get updated as i change qty but for grand total i am not able to do . 
here is is my code

```
  <?php 
                                if(isset($_POST['prod_id'])){
                                    $prod_id =$_POST['prod_id'];
                                    $prod_qty=$_POST['qty'];
                                    $up_cart="UPDATE `cart` SET `qty` = '$prod_qty' WHERE `cart`.`product_id` = '$prod_id'";
                                    $up_cart_run = mysqli_query($conn,$up_cart);
                                    if($up_cart_run){
                                        echo "done";
                                    }

                                }
                                ?>


                                    <?php       


                                        $cart_item_query="SELECT * FROM cart";
                                        $cart_item_run = mysqli_query($conn,$cart_item_query);
                                        if (mysqli_num_rows($cart_item_run)>0){
                                            $grand_total=0;
                                            while($cart_row=mysqli_fetch_array($cart_item_run)){
                                                $pro_id = $cart_row['product_id'];
                                                $pro_qty = $cart_row['qty'];


                                                $product_query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id'";
                                                $product_run = mysqli_query($conn, $product_query);
                                                $product_row = mysqli_fetch_array($product_run);
                                                $pro_name = $product_row['product_name'];
                                                $pro_image = $product_row['product_image'];
                                                $pro_sell_price = $product_row['sell_price'];
                                                $total = $pro_sell_price*$pro_qty;
                                                $grand_total =$grand_total+ $total;


                                    ?>

                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><img src="img/<?php echo $pro_image; ?>" alt="" width="50px"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><p><?php echo $pro_name; ?></p><a href=""><p><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Remove</p></a></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                                            <select class="change_qty" size="1" style="width:50px;">
                                                <?php
                                                for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
                                                    $selected = $pro_qty == $i? 'selected' : '';
                                                    echo "<option class='qty' data-pro='{$pro_id}' value='{$i}' {$selected}>{$i}</option>";
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><input data-pro="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" id="price-<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $pro_sell_price; ?>" disabled class="form-control dis-input price"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><input id="total-<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" data-pro="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" disabled class="form-control dis-input total"></div>

                                    </div>

                                    <hr>

                                    <?php

                                            }
                                        }

                                    ?>




                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div id="cart_total"></div>

                                <h3>TOTAL <span class="pull-right" id="grand_total">RS. <?php echo $grand_total;?></span></h3> <br>
                                <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">PLACE ORDER</a><br>
                                <h5>ORDER SUMMARY</h5>
                                <P>Total Price <span class="pull-right">RS.50000</span> </P>
                                <P>Discount <span class="pull-right text-success">- Rs.0</span> </P>
                                <P>Sub Total <span class="pull-right">Rs.60000</span> </P>
                                <P>Estimated GST <span class="pull-right">Rs.0</span> </P>
                                <P>Delivery Charges <span class="pull-right">Rs.0</span> </P><hr>
                                <h5>Total Payable <span class="pull-right">RS. 60000</span> </h5>


                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And here is js

```
$('body').delegate('.change_qty','change',function(){
         var qty = $(this).val();
        var prod_id = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-pro');
        var price = $('#price-'+prod_id).val();
        var total = qty*price;
        $('#total-'+prod_id).val(total);


        up_cart();
        function up_cart(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'cart.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{prod_id:prod_id,
                      qty:qty
                     },
                success:function(response){

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Now everything is working fine except grand total. grand total updates on page refresh but i want it to update as changes qty like price. Thanks.

Comment: You never do anything to update inside the success function?

Comment: Usually when doing these things using AJAX you send back responses which contain the data you need to update the front-end accordingly.

Comment: @apokryfos sir, can u explain me in details in m case?

Comment: Hi there kohali, in your cart.php does it output your grand total?

Comment: @james . yes but for that need page refresh which i dont want

Comment: Okay, so I am guessing your AJAX call is querying the same page the user is on then? I would probably make yourself a new script that only works out the grand total and use that in your AJAX call instead.

Comment: @James Sir and how it will look like ... i am new to this can u please explain in details or any example

Comment: hello developers, any answer for my question?

Comment: You need to share your `cart.php` code

Comment: @apokryfos above code is cart.php

Comment: That's just messy. At any rate in your success you could replace the corresponding contents using `$("#grand_total).text($(response).find("#grand_total"))` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a PHP-File, for example something like "calc_grand_total.php" or so, and use this instead of "cart.php" in your ajax call. 
In your PHP-File you should calculate the grand total with the parameters which you send to the file and after that you return the grand total of the article.
in the success function of the ajax call you can output and refresh the grand total in the cart.php with jQuery.